# Chrome caught with function(){debugger()} in web page using inspect

Tags: function, google-chrome, debugging, inspect

When trying to look at web pages that have excessive amounts of ads in them using Chrome's inspect, I find that some of them now have an embedded `function(){debugger;}` clause in them.

Chrome brings up a panel like this:

```
(function() {
debugger
})
```

This causes chrome to pause even when I have it set to **Don't pause on exceptions.**

Is there a way to get chrome to not do this?
How can I get chrome to ignore this function call?